# How can i replace some "this" only outside functions?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to replace some "this" in a script.

```
$(this).find('option').each(function() {

    $(this).hide();
})
```

Is there a possibility to replace only the outer this, or only the "this" that are not inside a function block? My idea doesn't work ...

```
.replace(/([^{])\bthis\b([^}])/gm, $1replacement$2)
```

addendum: The first code is handled as a string, not as javascript!
I am search for a regexp to replace only the outer "this".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the replace supposed to be doing? What should `.hide()` be hiding?

Comment: U mean from the above example u want to replace **"this"** in `$(this).find()` and not replace `$(this).hide()`..?

Comment: @NREZ Yes! The first code is a STRING not javascript. It is an interpreter from Structured Text (ST) to Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to distinguish "outer" from "inner" text is that for inner, the next curly bracket is a *right* one, which closes the block its in.

So, using a negative look ahead to exclude `this` within a block:

```
str = str.replace(/\bthis\b(?![^{]*\})/gs, replacement);
```

Also note the simplification of the replacement term, since the match is *just* the target text "this".

See a [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bD9cL4) of this regex working.

Comment: /@user2739158 I stupidly left an equal sign `!=` instead of `!` in the negative look ahead. Also changed the flag to `s` from `m`. It works now. see [link](http://regex101.com/r/bD9cL4)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are wanting to refer to the `$(this)` variable from within your function, however that variable gets changed to the local scope of the function. So within the function, `$(this)` will refers to the item you are currently iterating over.

You'll want to cache the scope of the `$(this)` object before you enter your function.

```
var cached_this = $(this);
$(this).find('option').each(function() {
    cached_this.hide();
})
```

Now you have access the value of the outer `$(this)` from within a different scope using the `cached_this` variable.

Comment: `$(this).find` could then be replaced too ;)

Answer (score 0):

In that case *this* is an object. It's not a string that you can replace. You may assign another value, but such a replacement will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only certain divs, simply change your jQuery selector to select those with a certain class, or child elements of a parent div, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Due to this function you can replace `this` object:

```
$(this).find('option').each(function() {
    // here this === replacement
    $(this).hide();
}.call(replacement))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a function, you can "replace" `this` by assigning a different variable to it when you call it.

```
var func = function() {
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
};

func.apply(annotherThis);
```